# How to realize a fixed-width div with scrolling content on hover?

Tags: html, firefox, css, overflow, css-transitions

I am trying to create a div containing 2 divs: one for a cover img and the other div with some text.
I would love to show only the image and move it away on hover to show the text.
I wrote this code using absolute positioning and css transitions but there's something wrong.

It works great in Chrome but it doesn't in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/5NHh2/4/

Could someone help me?
I think the problem is the overflow:hidden set to the main div.

Thank you very much

This is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="info-box">
    <a href="#" title="">
        <div class="cover">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/180x267" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h5>A Title</h5>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div>​
```

And this is the css:

```
    .container {
        background:#000;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px;
    }
    .info-box{
        text-align:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
        background:#ddd;
        display:inline-table;
        margin:0 10px 10px;
    }
    .info-box,
    .info-box img,
    .info-box .cover {
        width:180px;
        height:267px;
    }
    .info-box a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#333;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:180px;
        height:534px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    .info-box .info {
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 2px #000;
    }
    .info-box a:hover{
        top:-267px;
    }
    .info-box .info {
        width:160px;
        height:247px;
        padding:10px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .info {
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    }
    .info-box .info h5 {
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS',Arial,sans-serif;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space:nowrap;
        text-overflow:ellipsis;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `.container, .info-box {overflow:hidden;}` to the end.

Works in firefox for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/5NHh2/5/